# Convert string of an array of serialized json object to array of string

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have a problem deserializing an http response that is an array of different json object serialized into a string, what I want to achieve is building an array of string in which each string is a serialized json object different from the others.

This is the string I start with (it's not well formatted, but you get the point)

```vb
Dim response as String = "[{""test"":""test""}, {""prova"":""prova""}, {""test1"":""test1""}, {""test2"":""test2""}]"
```

**What i tried**

I tried simply to deserialize it as an array of string

```vb
Dim payload As String() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of String())(response)
```

but of course I get the Exception:

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 2."

How can I avoid that?

Comment: But the JSON shown is *not* an array of strings.  It's an array of objects.  (And a malformed one at that, so deserialization of any kind should be expected to fail.)  Maybe you want to deserialize it into an array of such objects (the dynamic structure may be a challenge) and then serialize those back into JSON strings?  Alternatively you'd be looking at writing your own deserializer.

Comment: Ahh I see the problem, because the object are not between quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let JsonConvert deserialize  the entire string into an array of objects like it expects, rather than strings, and then reserialize each item in the array one at a time.

```vb
Dim response as String = "[{""test"":""test""}, {""prova"":""prova""}, {""test1"":""test1""}, {""test2"":""test2""}]"
Dim payload() As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JArray)(response).
        Select(Function(o) JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o)).
        ToArray()
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlqDfB

You can simplify this further by reducing the `.Select()` delegate to a simple `.ToString()` call, but you end up with a bunch of extra whitespace you might not need or want.

Answer (score 2):

just one line of code

```
Dim payload As String() = JArray.Parse(response)
                                .Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()
```